# A2P and P2P messaging routing

Tags: routes, sms, twilio, p2p

Please explain by details, how do A2P and P2P messaging differ in routing to different countries.

Imagine I am going to send a SMS to my friend in a **different country**. My questions is, what route does the message travel to reach my friend in these two situations:

a) I send him a SMS with my mobile phone directly which is a P2P messaging.

b) I send him a SMS with an application like Twilio which is A2P messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The difference is down to which party constructs the message, connects to the [PSTN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_switched_telephone_network) and instructs it to send the message. In the case of sending a message from your phone, you connect to your network provider and initiate the message. In terms of Twilio, you would need to [make an API call to our REST API to send the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and then Twilio would connect to the PSTN via our agreements with various carriers and send the message.

Other differences are that with your phone you would send from the number on your SIM card, with Twilio you would need to [buy and use a Twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) to send from (as we don't allow number spoofing when sending SMS messages).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @philnash, but I didn't get my answer. Your answer was general. I was looking for a detailed guide which tells me exactly what path does the message travel to get to the destination. E.g. first goes to BTS antenna, then SMSC, then ... .
Knowing the exact route, I can understand how A2P messages get filtered by carriers, but P2P messages reach the destination with no filtering.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you're looking for specific details on how this works with Twilio, particularly if you are finding that messages aren't getting through, then I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supply some message SIDs for messages that didn't arrive.